# Is it possible to automatically cast by method signature

Tags: java, casting

Is there a way to do something like this:

```java
public class Controler{

    public String doSomething(int i){
        Service s = new Service();
        A a = s.doIt(i);
        return this.doSmthingWithA(a);
    }

    private static String doSmthingWithA(A a) {
        return "a";
    }

    private static String doSmthingWithA(B b) {
        return "b";
    }

    private static String doSmthingWithA(C c) {
        return "c";
    }
}

class A {
}

class B extends A {
}

class C extends A {
}

class Service{
    public A doIt(int i){
        if(i == 1){
            return new B();
        }
        return new C();
    }
}
```

And the unit test

```java
@Test
public void t(){
    Controler c = new Controler();
    Assert.assertEquals("b",c.doSomething(1));
    Assert.assertEquals("c",c.doSomething(2));
}
```

Now, I always got `c.doSomething(1)` equals to "a" or I want to find a way without explicit cast. This example is very simple, but in my case I use it to simplify a catch expression in my app with more than 15 different checked exceptions.

Comment: You can only do this by applying `instanceof` checks (or similar) and calling the right method with an explicit cast. Method resolution is done at compile-time, and given the type of the variable `a` is `A`, it will select the method `doSmthingWithA(A)`. The fact that at runtime it might have a value of `B` or `C` doesn't come into consideration.

Comment: I thnk, this problem is sometime solved with the [visitor design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example). Visitor does need neither instanceof nor casts. You need to be able to modify classes A, B, and C, though.

Comment: @ThomasBehr, I don't know this design pattern. I build a poc and it's work but if i'm right, I should use a interface with a void visit(Visitor visitor) method, but In my case it's inpossible cause of catch clause expect a Throwable class. So I use an abstract class wich extends Exception.
I think it's ok thx a lot